# How do I split a "data.frame" type column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` where one of the columns `user` is itself a `data.frame`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  user = data.frame(
    id = numeric(),
    name = character()
  )
)

df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c(1,"joe")
```

How do I split the `user` column into the `id` and `name` columns so that `df` has the `id` and `name` columns instead of the `user` column?

Comment: From the example, the `df` is still a normal data.frame.  Please check the `str(df)`

Comment: It works for me in Rstudio...

Comment: For me, it is showing `str(df)#
'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ user.id  : chr "1"
 $ user.name: chr "joe"` with R 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` on the column names after converting it to a regular data.frame

```
df <-  do.call(data.frame, df) 
names(df) <- sub("^user\\.", "", names(df))
```